# One vagrant command to create and provision machine whether machine is created or not?

Tags: virtual-machines, vagrant, command, provisioning

When my **VM is not created**, I can run:

```
vagrant up
```

or:

```
vagrant up --provision
```

but not `vagrant provision`, because of the warning:

> VM not created. Moving on...

When my **VM is created**, I can run:

```
vagrant provision
```

or:

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

but not `vagrant up --provision`, because of the warning:

> The machine is already created.

When I run `vagrant up && vagrant provision`, it will be provisioned twice if VM machine hasn't been created yet.

Also I can't check for the non-zero exit code of above commands to run another, because they're always returning zero.

Is there any single vagrant command which will invoke the provision script every time when I run the command independently of the VM state (whether it is created or not)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a single command, but perhaps this will work:

```
$ vagrant up --no-provision && vagrant provision
```